# Hide javascript injections from chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, detection, chromium-embedded, javascript-injection

I am writing code to inject javascript into a chromium-based browser (cefsharp). Sometimes when I inject the javascript, the browser says something like: "chrome detected unusual activity that could be browser automation" (sorry I don't have the exact error). Anyways, the javascript doesn't work. Keep in mind this is only on some websites. Any ideas as to what is causing this and/or how I could hide my injection/mask it as normal user activity.

As a side note, to put aside any doubts, I am injecting only my own (or my friends') websites.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How are you trying to inject the javascript?

Comment: @MatthewCrumley in c# I'm using   `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("jsScript");`

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP